# Formats of texts from wikisource?

Tags: data-format, text

In what formats can I retrieve texts from wikisource?

The obvious format is the HTML they deliver for reading, but the HTML source is very layout oriented and messy.

Is there a downloadable source format available that is more logical (XML or wiki format)? How can I download it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For automated processing, by far the best alternative is a [database dump](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/).  They might be a little bit old, but hopefully that won't be a problem.

You can select database dumps by language and wiki, with or without edit history.

At the time of writing, [the most recent enwikisource dump is from 26 December 2015](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwikisource/20160111/).  You can also find dumps for [dewikisource](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/dewikisource/), [frwikisource](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/frwikisource/), etc.

Comment: Age is not a problem, but size matters: I am basically interested in a selection of about 2 dozen texts.

Comment: @jknappen That's more of a (mediawiki) technical question.  There's probably a forum somewhere on wikimedia to ask it.

Comment: I found out that I can export all pages from one category using Special:Export (available in the "special pages" menue). To get at the textual content, I had to check the box "include templates". The format is still crowded, but ways better than the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just interested in two dozen text I think it is easiest just to request for the raw wikitext, for instance for the 'The Metal Pig' page:

```
https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Metal_Pig?action=raw
```

This query returns the raw wikitext, i.e., with unexpanded templates and category links.